# How do I allocate free disk space to my Ubuntu 22.04 partition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, fdisk, disk-management

I have read and tried the mentioned methods of allocating free space to my Ubuntu partition and have been unable to succeed.  I have tried both gparted and the Disk Utility application provided with Ubuntu 22.04.  I believe that I may need to move the Free Space to the right of Partition 6 prior to increasing the size of Partition 6 but and again, cannot do so.  I might add that all of my efforts were done from a USB thumb drive using "Try Ubuntu".

[image: Disk Utility Image]

gparted image 1

[image: gparted image 1]

gparted image 2

[image: gparted image 2]

gparted correct image 2

[image: gparted correct image 2]

Comment: Can you create a new partition in the free space to the left (273 GB)? I'm thinking you might be successful doing that, then copying the current partition 6 data to it, then deleting partition 6, then resizing the new partition. It's odd that partitions 2-5 are missing, which makes me wonder whether your partition table has gotten honked up somehow.

Comment: Is your goal to have a single Ext4 partition? Or would you be satisfied with two (or more) partitions? 

Comment: Would prefer one partition.  To your point, Gary, 2-5 are missing because (stupid me, half asleep) deleted all NTFS partitions to get rid of Windows completely.  I wasn't satisfied with just freeing up as much space as possible.  user68186, I added a gparted screenshot above.  Gary, I might try your suggestion.  It would seem plausible.

Comment: Gary, I cannot format the free space.  I cannot do anything with it, all options are unavailable.

Comment: user68186 - I tried and the best i could do was with my phone.  I could not save screenshots to a place where I could retrieve them.  You are exposing my ignorance because I am sure it can be done but...

Comment: They are up in the original question, not sure how to upload an image in this section.

Comment: user68186 - can i format the unallocated then expand partition 6?

Comment: i sent one by mistake that was from my laptop, the rest are all from a boot usb

Comment: From the live USB, click on the Resize/Move as shown in "Gparted correct image 2" and take a picture. If you can **drag the left edge all the way to the left** try that. If you get an error take a picture. If it works, don't forget to click on the Green check icon as seen in the very top screenshot and accept the changes.

Comment: You don't do anything with unallocated. You select a partition and expand it.

Comment: Select the partition `/dev/nvmen0n1p6` and selest `Resize/Move` from the `Partition`-menu (last screenshot), of course, do it while booted from your USB-thumbdrive with `try Ubuntu`

Comment: Pilot6 - Thanks for input but, if you read all of the dialogue and look at all the images, you may have been been unable to decipher my feeble attempts at explaining, you will find that all your suggestions have been attempted with no positive results.  I cannot drag 6 to the left, i cannot move it to the left.  Unallocated gives me no options.  There are no error messages.  My last question stands, if I format the unallocated, will that give me the ability to then expand 6 to the left or move 6 to the left and expand to the right?

Comment: Pilot6 - I owe you an apology and a huge thank you to all who participated and helped and gave comments.  It worked!!!  Steps:  boot from usb, open terminal, execute gparted, selct partion6, select Partion from the menu bar, select Move/Resize, a window pops up whereby one can drag the partion.  Again thanks to all!!!  How do I close this topic/question and provide feedback?

Comment: @phil Please delete the question. Otherwise the question will be first reviewed by several volunteers and "closed" as a duplicate, Next it will be reviewed by another group of volunteers for deletion. You can do it easily. It will take more time for more of us to delete the question.